# Not able to launch Atom IDE in Normal Mode but works just fine in in Safe Mode

Tags: github, atom-editor

Recently I encountered a problem with Atom IDE that whenever I launch the IDE (either by clicking the icon or launching it via terminal), atom launches in a very weird form (Image below). I don't know a workaround to get to the actual work area. A strange part being it works just fine whenever I launch it in safe mode (atom --safe). This problem wasn't there anytime before. I am using it since months but never got this problem.
I don't want to open atom everytime using the safe mode command.

I have tried uninstalling and installing it again and even tried to reset all the configurations but nothing helped.

Operating System : Linux Mint Cinnamon 18.1

[image]

Comment: The fact that it works in safe mode suggests that a plugin you have installed is crashing? Plugins are stored in ~/.atom, not sure if uninstalling atom removes the plugins.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I had to delete every package one by one to check it. I thought re-installing atom removes all the plugins but I was wrong. Apathy-Theme was the culprit.